# Lower bound for $\ln x$ using Lagrange's mean value theorem or Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

I have to prove this inequality.

> $$
> \ln x>\frac{2(x-1)}{x+1}  \hspace{15pt}, \hspace{15pt}\text{where}\hspace{5pt}x>1
> $$

using either Lagrange's mean value theorem or Rolle's theorem. Can someone give me a little hint?

Answer (score 4):

Define

$$f(x):=\log x-2\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\log x-2\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\,\,,\,x>1\Longrightarrow$$

$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{4}{(x+1)^2}> 0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{(x-1)^2}{x(x+1)^2}>0$$

and the last inequality is true for any $\,x>1\,$ , so $\,f\,$ is a non-decreasing function in $\,(1,\infty)\,$ , and thus

$$\forall\,\,x>1\;\;,\;\;f(x)>f(1)=0$$

... and without Lagrange or Rolle...!

**Added:** Ok, with Lagrange's MVT (*sigh!*):

Being $\,f(x)\,$ the same function as above, we get that for *any* $\,x>1\,$ there exists $\,c\in(1,x)\,$ s.t.:

$$\frac{\log x-2\frac{x-1}{x+1}}{x-1}=\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(c)>0$$

the demonstration of the rightmost inquality being the same as in the first part, and since $\,x-1>0\,$ we get at once $\,f(x)-f(1)>0\,$ , which is the wanted inequality.

Comment: Don Antonio de Mendoza, I need this by Lagrange or Rolle. Gracias.

Comment: or Rolle*  or  Rolle

Comment: You can think of it as implicitly using Legrange, since $f(x)-f(1) = (x-1)f'(c)$ for somr $c\in(1,x)$, and hence $f(x)-f(1)>0$ since $f'(c)>0$ and $x>1$, so $f(x)>f(1)=0$